# Can i do command "service network restart" on dedicated server?

Tags: networking, openvz

If i do "service network restart" Linux command on my OpenVZ VPS host server (dedicated server where are virtual machines - VPSs hosted), how this can impact virtual machines? Can i loose SSH connectivity, why not?

Comment: It will interrupt the network connection of all virtual machines ...restarting "network" basically does a down/up cycle of your network interface. Is there really any reason to do this?

Answer (score 4):

**Can you restart the network service? (on the openvz host.. etc..)**

Yes

**What will happen?**

Best case scenario: Nothing (horribly detrimental that is)

Worst Case: Loss of networking on the host. Loss of **any** connectivity to the host. Loss of **any** connectivity to the VMs. Critical Application failures on the VMs due to network connectivity issues. Corruption of databases etc.

The server could also explode killing everyone in the datacenter... (But there is just always a risk that the server was armed with a high yield nuclear device and the trigger was the `service network restart` command... Those are just risks most of us are willing to accept).

### We can't tell you what will happen.

We don't know your VMs or their applications or even your network configuration. We **don't** recommend you do this unless you have a **very VERY** good concrete reason to do so... and even then we would urge you to find a way to do what you need without interrupting the network connectivity.